# Is this possible/advisable to establish SAMBA share across domains?

Tags: user-accounts, samba, nfs

*I realize this question will likely turn out rather complex and require a lenghty description. Likewise there’ll probably not be any short simple answer.*

I’ve got a large data-store (a SAN) that is made available to several users in one domain through a samba server (version 3.6.x currently). The SAN and server sits in a separate domain/environment.

The thing is that the users also work in another domain, and I would like to expand access to the share to this second domain.

**Proposed solution** 
[image]

My initial idea on how to reach the goal of giving access to the SAMBA share in the second domain is the following:

The file-system that is the SAMBA share is first “exposed” to a local server in the second domain through NFS. You might wonder why, this is done because there’s a large geographical/network distance between the first SAMBA server and the second domain, so this is mainly for performance reasons.

Once the server in the second domain obtains the SAMBA share through NFS it will act as a SAMBA server and distribute the share to the users on their clients.

**Issues**

I think the main issue here will be user accounts, and ownership, permissions and such on the filesystem of the SAMBA share.

The accounts the users log in with in the two domains are unrelated, they have essentially nothing in common.

Currently authentication is set to `security = User` in the samba server, authentication and access is done with local account on the server. Previously auth was done against an AD-server in the first domain, but we ran into some issues and changed to local accounts.

The filesystem that is the samba share is basically set up so that there's a number of common shared folders with the ownership `nobody:usergroup` and private folders with the ownership `<user>:usergroup`. (Every user is a member of `usergroup`)

I am leaning towards relying upon local account instead of involving Active Directory, because this is a small group of people and it looks like it could simplify things quite a bit. In that case, all that would have to be done is to sync accounts between the two servers.

Do you think that is is, by large, possible? Do you see any major problems that could arise with this setup?

Comment: So is this question about Microsoft or Linux setups? Please clarify?

Comment: Is upgrading to Samba 4.x a possible option?

Answer (score -1):

Create a forest with both domains members

1. **Universal Groups**:

   - **MEMBER INCLUSION**: *Users, Computer Accounts, Global Groups, and Universal Groups **FROM ANY DOMAIN***
   - **PERMISSIONS**: *Within any domain, universal groups can be added to other groups and granted permissions.*
2. **Global Groups**:

   - **MEMBER INCLUSION**: *Any user or computer acct or other global groups from the same Domain*
   - **PERMISSIONS**: *Global groups can be added to other global  groups in any domain in the forest and assigned permissions*
3. **Domain Local Groups**:

   - **MEMBER INCLUSION**: *Same as universal groups, but you can also include domain local groups from the same Domain.*
   - **PERMISSION**: Domain loval groups can be added only to other domain local groups in the same domain and assigned permissions.

**EDIT:** I was thinking you were talking all Microsoft and you’re probably in Linux now that I see Samba share. I may have just confused myself. I’m a student, sorry if this is not useful.